# Seg Fault with SOCI

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

So I haven't been coding in C++ for quite a while now, but I'm pretty sure this issue is related to SOCI and not some general knowledge of memory usage in C++. Here is the problem : I'm using SOCI to query a table and get a field, and the sql statement line always cause a Segmentation Fault. Which is quite troublesome... Here is the code :

```
string engine::getReview(int rev_id) 
{
    try {
        session sql;
        string post;

        sql.open("mysql", "db=ranking_dev user=****** password=*******");
        sql << "SELECT post FROM reviews WHERE id = 3", into(post); //Faulty line

        return post;
    }
    catch (exception const &e) {
        cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
        return "";
    }
}
```

I'm positive that this line is the root of the error. I tried to initialize the "post" variable, but to no avails. Also, if I retrieve an integer value from the table (and thus store the data in an integer), there's no SEG FAULT. And so I guess the issue is related to the way I'm using this string, but I can see anything overly wrong in my function. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Is that comma before `into(post)` a typo? What does `into()` return?

Comment: No, it's part of the syntax.  SOCI is overloading the comma operator here

Comment: What's the data type for the `post` column? AFAIK only STRING/BINARY/VARCHAR/VARBINARY are convertible to std::string

Comment: The data type is "text" (I just noticed, I thought it was varchar)... But I did try to change the query to get a varchar field, and I still get a SEG Fault.

Comment: Try posting the relevant stack frames from the core dump.  Someone may see something useful there.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to get this, I'm using netbeans and it actually doesn't give lot of information...

Comment: The program has no error (checked it against Oracle). Since you have not provided the stack trace, my guess is that the error is related to the database connectivity `sql.open(...` statement. Can you check whether you have the database native drivers in proper location? Note that SOCI does not bundle the database drivers. You need to provide the appropriate DB drivers which will be used by SOCI to connect to the DB on your behalf.